# Elegant way to throw exception on empty stream

Tags: java, exception, java-stream, coding-style

I am fetching list of clients. Then I map enitity to dto and return result. I would like to throw exception on empty client list, but also I want to avoid if statement in code.

I can wrap list in optional but I believe there is more elegant solution.

```
Set<ClientDto> clients = Optional.of(repo.findByNumber(number))
                .filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException())
                .stream()
                .map(client -> new ClientDto(client.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Is there any cleaner solution? Because there is few usless chains in my code. I am even now starting to think that pure if would be more readable.

Comment: I think using an `if` here is more suitable than doing gymnastics with streams, because the stream operation doesn't depend on whether the list is empty. The stream operation will succeed no matter if the list is empty or not.

Comment: If you *don’t believe in if anymore*, you may do `repo.findByNumber(number).stream().findAny().orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException());` (I beleve that for me I’d prefer the `if` statement).

Comment: To complete what Sweeper pointed out, formatted to  match the number of lines of the code in question -- `Collection<Data> data = repo.findByNumber(number);
        if (data.isEmpty()) throw new NotFoundException("");
        Set<ClientDto> clients = data.stream()
                .map(client -> new ClientDto(client.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());` is much better than wrapping within `Optional`.

Comment: @OleV.V.  You'd lose(or have to process/query again) the rest of the data using `findAny` as compared to the collected one in the question. For such a check as in your code `exists` from a repository should be a better lookup.

Comment: Yes, @Naman, I know, that’s true (if the find operation is costly, one may save its result to a variable and only do the stream operation again).

Comment: at this stage I chose stupid if. I just thought that there is syntatic sugar for such case in java 11+

Comment: Your solution can’t work that way. `Optional.stream()` produces a stream of zero or one element, the contained element. Since that element is supposed to be the collection you tested via `CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty`, it can’t be an object having a `getName()` method at the same time. There’s at least a `flatMap` step or similar missing. It seems, you want to do something like `Set<ClientDto> clients = repo.findByNumber(number) .map(client -> new ClientDto(client.getName())) .collect(Collectors.toSet());`, so you should do exactly that. You can do  `if(clients.isEmpty()) throw …` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you can do it with pure streams but you could define a method which returns a stream of the list and throw an exception if its empty.

```java
private <T> Stream<T> throwIfEmpty(List<T> list) {
    if(list.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("List must not be empty");
    }
    return list.stream();
}
```

then you could use it the following way:

```java
List<Client> clients = throwIfEmpty(repo.findByNumber(number))
    .map(client -> new ClientDto(client.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

maybe this solution makes you happy :)

Comment: I ve been thinkig about that, but the problem is that I would like to throw there bussiness exception. So this method should accept then exception and after that this code again is starting to look uglier than stupid if ;( i just thought that there is already some syntatic sugar for that case in java 11...14